# Can I replace potassium nitrate with sodium nitrate in a smoke bomb?

Tags: experimental-chemistry, home-experiment

A very famous experiment goes like this:

$\ce{KNO3}$, molten wax and sugar are mixed and later burnt; the resulting mixture produces quite a lot of smoke.

After hearing about the experiment, I threw in the idea, "What would happen if $\ce{NaNO3}$, or other alkaline compounds were used instead?". However, the teacher wants us to be sure that the building doesn't explode. So here I am. Has this experiment been attempted before? What would happen if it was used?

[Here](http://styropyro.com/tutorials/smokebomb.htm) is a link with the smoke bomb experiment.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In pyrotechnics, $\ce{NaNO3}$ is normally avoided because it is very hygroscopic.

With dried $\ce{NaNO3}$, the effect should be identical.

In any case, the usual safety rules apply!

Comment: @MikhailTal Have fun, but play safe and protect your eyes!

Comment: We didn't do it, we'll do it later, but still, I'll accept it.